# How to get its prototype object of an object in ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

```
object1=Object.new
object2=object1.clone
puts object1==object2.prototype #this statement doesn't work!
```

Can we get an object's prototype (like javascript's .prototype)in ruby?
In other words, how to get parent object?

Comment: I'm probably the only Ruby programmer who doesn't know javascript, but can you describe an object's prototype briefly? Does it mean "this is the object from which I got most of my methods"?

Comment: an object's prototype means the object which it is cloned from. object1 is the prototype of object2 , in above case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby is a class-based OO language, not a prototype-based one. Objects don't *have* prototypes, they have classes.

So, the answer is: no, you cannot get an object's prototype, because you cannot get something which never existed in the first place.

Comment: What happens with the eigenclass when an object gets cloned? Does the eigenclass get copied, or does it point at the first object's eigenclass to start off with?

Comment: A fairly clear approach (warning: uses evil ruby!) is here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ruby%20prototype&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ft-a-w.blogspot.com%2F2006%2F10%2Fprototype-based-ruby.html&ei=kjDxT4_eJ4yI8QSy2dD_AQ&usg=AFQjCNFTN20LKYNXR83AArt3PQq_hsV8fw&sig2=L3nKMor7-s35qfnLiJGtTA